# convert cursor to a set based operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

So I have this query which searches id by id and calculates the cost accordingly. But is very slow and I would like to understand how I could convert it into a set based operation.

So depending on our condition we calculate our modeled costs differently.

When user updates a driver we can run a update on the entire driver column based on where it has changed.

But when it comes to calculating the modeled cost.  **We do it row by row as the fixed cost differs**  and then divide by months. I have pasted the code below. Is there still a way to this by set based operation ?

First we update the drivers in the same table depending on what value has changed using an update and then update the modeled cost row by row (which is really slow)

Code :

```
SELECT @rowCounter = 1, @totalrows = @@ROWCOUNT

WHILE @rowCounter <= @totalrows
    BEGIN

        SELECT @currentId = tempId
        FROM @temp
        WHERE row = @rowCounter     

        SELECT  
                @newModeledCost = 
                case when not exists (select 1 from dbo.DIMSTD_SCENARIO where SCENARIO0_Name = SCENARIO and SCENARIO2_Name = 'Model') then 
                ISNULL(DriverValue1,0)*ISNULL(DriverValue2,0)*ISNULL(UnitA,0)*ISNULL(UnitB,0)+ISNULL(FixedCost,0) 
                -- normal allocation for all scenarios
                else
                (ISNULL(unita,0) * (ISNULL(DriverValue1,0)/ISNULL(NULLIF(DriverValue2,0),1))* ISNULL(UnitB,0))+ISNULL(FixedCost,0)  
                --(ISNULL(unita,0) * (ISNULL(DriverValue1,0)/ISNULL(DriverValue2,0))*ISNULL(UnitB,0))+ISNULL(FixedCost,0) 
                -- allocation for model scenarios
                end
                ,                                       
                @oldModeledCost = ISNULL(ModeledCost,0),
                @newOct = (ISNULL(@newModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Oct, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(@oldModeledCost,0),1))),
                @newNov = (ISNULL(@newModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Nov, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(@oldModeledCost,0),1))),
                @newDec = (ISNULL(@newModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Dec, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(@oldModeledCost,0),1))),
                @newJan = (ISNULL(@newModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Jan, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(@oldModeledCost,0),1))),
                @newFeb = (ISNULL(@newModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Feb, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(@oldModeledCost,0),1))),
                @newMar = (ISNULL(@newModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Mar, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(@oldModeledCost,0),1))),
                @newApr = (ISNULL(@newModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Apr, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(@oldModeledCost,0),1))),
                @newMay = (ISNULL(@newModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(May, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(@oldModeledCost,0),1))),
                @newJun = (ISNULL(@newModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Jun, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(@oldModeledCost,0),1))),
                @newJul = (ISNULL(@newModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Jul, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(@oldModeledCost,0),1))),
                @newAug = (ISNULL(@newModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Aug, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(@oldModeledCost,0),1))),
                @newSep = (ISNULL(@newModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Sep, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(@oldModeledCost,0),1)))
        FROM dbo.TBF_BUDGETExpenses
        WHERE BudgetId = @currentId 
        --and not exists (select 1 from dbo.DIMSTD_SCENARIO where SCENARIO0_Name = SCENARIO and SCENARIO2_Name = 'Model')

        UPDATE dbo.TBF_BUDGETExpenses
        SET ModeledCost = @newModeledCost,
            Oct = @newOct,
            Nov = @newNov,
            Dec = @newDec,
            Jan = @newJan,
            Feb = @newFeb,
            Mar = @newMar,
            Apr = @newApr,
            May = @newMay,
            Jun = @newJun,
            Jul = @newJul,
            Aug = @newAug,
            Sep = @newSep,
            Username = 'Cascade',
            lastmodified = getdate()                
        WHERE BudgetId = @currentId
        AND @oldModeledCost <> 0

        Print 'Record Update ' + CAST(@currentId AS VARCHAR(15))

        SET @rowCounter = @rowCounter + 1

END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you case, definitely set operation is better and feasible, but the best approach as I can think is not to use any query, but use DDL of table. When you create table, you can create computed columns with persisted. Like your twelve months columns, they can be computed columns, and all the factors paticipate in your computing actualy all from the same table. Here is the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186241.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to validate this without complete schema, test data, and expected results. This is a quick set based repro of your current update.  Note: I moved your ModeledCost `CASE` down into a subquery just to avoid repeating it in each column set. Up to you whether that makes logical sense or not... I assume BudgetId is the PK.

Run the update as a `SELECT` to confirm its producing the desired resultset:

```
select  t.BudgetId,
        --
        Oct = (ISNULL(new.ModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Oct, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(t.ModeledCost,0),1))),
        Nov = (ISNULL(new.ModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Nov, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(t.ModeledCost,0),1))),
        Dec = (ISNULL(new.ModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Dec, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(t.ModeledCost,0),1))),
        Jan = (ISNULL(new.ModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Jan, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(t.ModeledCost,0),1))),
        Feb = (ISNULL(new.ModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Feb, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(t.ModeledCost,0),1))),
        Mar = (ISNULL(new.ModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Mar, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(t.ModeledCost,0),1))),
        Apr = (ISNULL(new.ModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Apr, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(t.ModeledCost,0),1))),
        May = (ISNULL(new.ModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(May, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(t.ModeledCost,0),1))),
        Jun = (ISNULL(new.ModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Jun, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(t.ModeledCost,0),1))),
        Jul = (ISNULL(new.ModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Jul, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(t.ModeledCost,0),1))),
        Aug = (ISNULL(new.ModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Aug, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(t.ModeledCost,0),1))),
        Sep = (ISNULL(new.ModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Sep, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(t.ModeledCost,0),1)))
        Username = 'Cascade',
        lastmodified = getdate(),
        ModeledCost = new.ModeledCost
from    dbo.TBF_BUDGETExpenses as [t]
left
join    (   select  BudgetId,
                    case
                        when not exists (select 1 from dbo.DIMSTD_SCENARIO where SCENARIO0_Name = SCENARIO and SCENARIO2_Name = 'Model') 
                        then ISNULL(DriverValue1,0)*ISNULL(DriverValue2,0)*ISNULL(UnitA,0)*ISNULL(UnitB,0)+ISNULL(FixedCost,0) 
                        -- normal allocation for all scenarios
                        else (ISNULL(unita,0) * (ISNULL(DriverValue1,0)/ISNULL(NULLIF(DriverValue2,0),1))* ISNULL(UnitB,0))+ISNULL(FixedCost,0)  
                            --(ISNULL(unita,0) * (ISNULL(DriverValue1,0)/ISNULL(DriverValue2,0))*ISNULL(UnitB,0))+ISNULL(FixedCost,0) 
                            -- allocation for model scenarios
                    end
            from    dbo.TBF_BUDGETExpenses
        ) as new(BudgetId, ModeledCost) on t.BudgetId = new.BudgetId
where   ISNULL(t.ModeledCost,0) <> 0
```

As an `UPDATE`:

```
update  t
set     Oct = (ISNULL(new.ModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Oct, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(t.ModeledCost,0),1))),
        Nov = (ISNULL(new.ModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Nov, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(t.ModeledCost,0),1))),
        Dec = (ISNULL(new.ModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Dec, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(t.ModeledCost,0),1))),
        Jan = (ISNULL(new.ModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Jan, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(t.ModeledCost,0),1))),
        Feb = (ISNULL(new.ModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Feb, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(t.ModeledCost,0),1))),
        Mar = (ISNULL(new.ModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Mar, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(t.ModeledCost,0),1))),
        Apr = (ISNULL(new.ModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Apr, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(t.ModeledCost,0),1))),
        May = (ISNULL(new.ModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(May, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(t.ModeledCost,0),1))),
        Jun = (ISNULL(new.ModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Jun, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(t.ModeledCost,0),1))),
        Jul = (ISNULL(new.ModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Jul, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(t.ModeledCost,0),1))),
        Aug = (ISNULL(new.ModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Aug, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(t.ModeledCost,0),1))),
        Sep = (ISNULL(new.ModeledCost,0) * (ISNULL(Sep, 0) /ISNULL(NULLIF(t.ModeledCost,0),1)))
        Username = 'Cascade',
        lastmodified = getdate(),
        ModeledCost = new.ModeledCost
from    dbo.TBF_BUDGETExpenses as [t]
left
join    (   select  BudgetId,
                    case
                        when not exists (select 1 from dbo.DIMSTD_SCENARIO where SCENARIO0_Name = SCENARIO and SCENARIO2_Name = 'Model') 
                        then ISNULL(DriverValue1,0)*ISNULL(DriverValue2,0)*ISNULL(UnitA,0)*ISNULL(UnitB,0)+ISNULL(FixedCost,0) 
                        -- normal allocation for all scenarios
                        else (ISNULL(unita,0) * (ISNULL(DriverValue1,0)/ISNULL(NULLIF(DriverValue2,0),1))* ISNULL(UnitB,0))+ISNULL(FixedCost,0)  
                            --(ISNULL(unita,0) * (ISNULL(DriverValue1,0)/ISNULL(DriverValue2,0))*ISNULL(UnitB,0))+ISNULL(FixedCost,0) 
                            -- allocation for model scenarios
                    end
            from    dbo.TBF_BUDGETExpenses
        ) as new(BudgetId, ModeledCost) on t.BudgetId = new.BudgetId
where   ISNULL(t.ModeledCost,0) <> 0
```